# combine partitions to one disk image

Tags: linux, partition, boot, dd

I have 3 images. Each image was done by cloning (by dd) a partition (these partitions formatted using ext3 file system).
One partition is boot-able with GRUB1 (CentOS)

How can I combine them to one disk image?

(I can copy the partitions images using dd command, but I don't know how to create partitions table and make boot working).

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Clone a working system onto new hardware, etc.? Were the three partitions from different mount points on a single system?

Comment: What's the goal? you can use loopback devices to work with filesystem images, but modifying disk images rather than partition/filesystem images is a whole lot more tricky.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a disk image.  The following command will create a 10G [sparse image](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2009/07/05/creating-sparse-files-on-linux-hosts-with-dd/):

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=mydisk.img bs=1 count=0 seek=10G
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 1.6554e-05 s, 0.0 kB/s
# ls -lh mydisk.img
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 10G Jun 17 15:27 mydisk.img
```

Partition the image with fdisk:

```
# fdisk mydisk.img
```

Make sure you create partitions that are at least as large as the ones
you've imaged!  For this example I created the following layout:

```
# fdisk -l mydisk.img
Disk mydisk.img: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1305 cylinders, total 20971520 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5519250f

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
mydisk.img1            2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
mydisk.img2         2099200     4196351     1048576   83  Linux
```

Use `kpartx` to create devices corresponding to each one of the partitions:

```
# kpartx -av mydisk.img
add map loop0p1 (253:3): 0 2097152 linear /dev/loop0 2048
add map loop0p2 (253:4): 0 2097152 linear /dev/loop0 2099200
```

This will create entries under `/dev/mapper`:

```
# ls -l /dev/mapper
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       7 Jun 17 15:33 loop0p1 -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       7 Jun 17 15:33 loop0p2 -> ../dm-4
```

Now you can copy your partition images onto your partitions:

```
# dd if=image_of_partition_1.img of=/dev/mapper/loop0p1 bs=1M
# dd if=image_of_partition_2.img of=/dev/mapper/loop0p2 bs=1M
```

Now remove the device mappings:

```
# kpartx -dv mydisk.img
del devmap : loop0p2
del devmap : loop0p1
loop deleted : /dev/loop0
```

And you're all set!

**Notes**

- You could also accomplish the same thing by using `dd` and the `seek` parameter (to start writing at the appropriate offset in your disk image file) instead of using `kpartx`, but I think that using `kpartx` is less error-prone.
- This will not result in a bootable image.  If you want that, you'll also have to install a boot loader onto it.